# Can't Access to ExpandablelistView in fragment

Tags: android, fragment

MainActivity on startup add a fragment layout to Relativeview, then i send a data to fragment to add it to ExpandablelistView but my app shows me error that couldn't recognize ExpandablelistView.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentAddCatergory.onClickButtonListener {
private FragmentManager manager;
private FragmentTransaction transactionShowList;
private FragmentTransaction transactionAddCatergory;
private FragmentAddCatergory addCatergory;
private FragmentShowCategory showCategory;
private boolean addcategory;
private TextView txtAddCategory;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    manager = getFragmentManager();
    transactionShowList = manager.beginTransaction();
    showCategory = new FragmentShowCategory();
    addCatergory=new FragmentAddCatergory();
    transactionShowList.add(R.id.Fragment_container, showCategory);
    transactionShowList.commit();
    addcategory=false;
    txtAddCategory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtaddcategory);
    txtAddCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ChangeFragment();
        }
    });
}

public void ChangeFragment(){
    transactionAddCatergory=manager.beginTransaction();
    if (addcategory){
        transactionAddCatergory.replace(R.id.Fragment_container,addCatergory);
        txtAddCategory.setText("Do you want to see your List?Show me!");
        addcategory=false;
    }else{
        transactionAddCatergory.replace(R.id.Fragment_container,showCategory);
        txtAddCategory.setText("Do you want to add a Category?Create One");
        addcategory=true;
    }
    transactionAddCatergory.commit();
}

@Override
public void ClickButton(String group, String child) {
    FragmentShowCategory a=new FragmentShowCategory();
    a.showExpand(this,group,child);
}}
```

in last above code i make object from first fragment and send a data and in below code is code of first fragment

```
public class FragmentShowCategory extends Fragment {
private View view;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_expandable_list_view, container, false);
    return view;
}

public void showExpand(Context context, String g, String c) {
    Toast.makeText(context, g + " is " + c, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    HashMap<String, List<String>> carsDetails = DataProvider.getInfo(g, c);
    List<String> carsBrands = new ArrayList<String>(carsDetails.keySet());
    ItemClass adapter = new ItemClass(context, carsDetails, carsBrands);
    ExpandableListView list = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

but when i ran my app, i get error that i don't know why in line of:

**ExpandableListView list = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandList);**

i'd appreciate to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fragment's view hierarchy is not inflated automatically just because you created an instance of your fragment, as you do in `ClickButton`. The [onCreateView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) method that has to be called first in order to inflate your views is part of the [fragment's lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). You should let Android instantiate your fragment, and acquire it's instance through the [FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById(int)).

[This tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments) explains basics about fragments very well.